# How to get selected dropdownlist item's value and post it to controller?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii so don't know much! I want to know how to get my selected item in controller?

I've got model, view and Controller.

Here is my view

```
<?php

use app\models\kafedra\distance;

use yii\helpers\Html;

$items = ['1 курс','2 курс','3 курс','4 курс'];
$form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin(['method'=>'post', 'id'=>'courses','action'=>'spisgrp']);
echo $form->field($model,'status')->dropDownList($items,array(
    'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()',
    'prompt'=>'Выберите курс'
));
\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

here is my model

```
<?php

namespace app\models\kafedra\distance;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

class Distance extends Model{
   public $status;
   public function rules(){
       return array(
           array('status','required')
       );
   }
}
```

and here is my controller

```
class DistanceController extends Controller{

    public function actionIndex(){   
        $model = new Distance();
        return $this->render('index',array(
            'model' => $model
        ));
    }

     public function actionSpisgrp() {
         //What I must write here dude?
     }
}
```

the questions is, what i must write in Spisgrp function to get my selected item? I think the code itself is simple, so no difficulties there understanding what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

I have just made it. But if anyone got advices for me, much appreciated! so in actionSpisgrp() i wrote this

```
$status = $_POST['Distance'];
         echo $status['status'];
```

At least it gives me id of my courses))). So kinda it works for me.